# HomePage scrolling down after Login

Tags: java, android, xml, parallax

In my app after login screen I'm directed to Home Page but my homepage is scrolling at bottom.The code of my Home Page is below it consists of ParallaxScrollView inside LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">

    <com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView
        android:id="@+id/parallaxScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:parallax_factor="1.9"
        tools:context=".LandingActivity">

  /* Here there is a Relative Layout inside a Linear Layout which consists of two SliderLayout and HorizontalRecyclerView*/

 </com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ProgressBar
            style="@style/CustomProgressDialogWithTransparentBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_dialog" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollViewEventDetails.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);//if you move at the end of the scroll
```

Try it.

Comment: Actually I'm using a fragment